# Redux trigger Multiple times

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When i recive message from the Socket The function trigger once but inside the reducer it hit multiple times 3-5 each time a thing

```
  useEffect(()=>{
        socket.on('message', (data) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'InsertMessage',
                payload: { text: data.Message, sender: data.SenderSeries, timestamp: new Date(), ...data }
            })
            ScrollDown()
        })
    },[])
```

Here is where i listen to my socket case 'InsertMessage':

```
return [...state, action.payload];`
```

thats all my code and my socket does not send twice i checked it

Im using useSelector also in my code to call same thing idk what to do

Comment: Is there any other place in your code where the `InsertMessage` action is dispatched?

Comment: No there is not

Comment: only when i create message and its function and here on Socket.on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useEffect()` callback may be called multiple times, causing multiple callback functions to be registered for the same event. This happens specifically in development mode, where React intentionally calls the effect callback multiple times to detect bugs like this.

One solution is to return a cleanup function from the `useEffect()` callback. React will call it before setting up the new effect. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const callback = (data) => { dispatch(...) };
  socket.on('message', callback);
  return () => {
    socket.off('message', callback);
  };
}, [])
```

Comment: the problem is when i log on the effect it onlly appear one but in the reducer hit 3 or 2 time

Comment: While this may not fix your problem, this is still a valid suggestion. If you set up a subscription in an effect, you need to unsubscribe in the cleanup